# compiling ffmpeg with librtmp and libx264

Tags: iphone

I have compiled librtmp from http://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/ and also libx264.
I am finding it difficult to compile ffmpeg with --enable-librtmp and --enable-libx264 options.
Keep on getting Error: librtmp not found or Error: libx264 not found.
I have librtmp.a and libx264.a files in /usr/local/lib folder.
I don't know how to resolve this issue. If someone has compiled ffmpeg with librtmp enable please let me know how to do.
All the above is for iPhone 4.2/4.3 sdk with Intel mac 10.6.6.
Thank u very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated the dynamic linker run-time bindings since you installed librtmp and libx264?

You should run: ldconfig As root.

Answer (score 0):

Hi yeah I compiled ffmpeg with librtmp and libx264

make sure that libx264 is also configured with --enable-shared

AFAIK, ffmpeg may require shared library of libx264

also make sure that PKG_CONFIG_PATH value contatins the the folder path that includes libx264.pc and librtmp.pc files